# Chromium Adobe Flash Plugin

Tags: flash, chromium, plugins

So I've been running a Windows 7 / Ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual boot for a while, and have been having a weird issue with the Chromium Adobe Flash Plug-in working for some YouTube videos and not working for others. I'd like to do a complete un-install and re-install of the plug-in to Chromium, but I'm not sure how to do that correctly. Note that the Plug-in works fine in Firefox, so it's no big deal, but it is something I would like to see get fixed. Can someone please instruct me on how to un-install and re-install the Chromium plug-in?

Thanks, you all are the best!

Comment: I should note that I've been looking around here for similar questions, but I haven't seen one yet that addresses the chromium flash plug in specifically, so I figured it'd be fastest for me to post here. I've seen plenty of questions about flash, but none of them seem to be related to what's happening with me.

Comment: The problem may be due to the fact that Adobe doesn't produce a recent version of Flash Player for Linux. The latest version is 11.2 whereas the latest version for other platforms is 12.0 at time of writing. You may use Chrome instead that has the latest Flash version.

Comment: and btw, as you search for a solution for your problem just know that [Flash content will stop working in Chromium on Linux from this April, it has been announced.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/chromium-npapi-flash-dropped-april-2014)

Comment: Thanks guys! And Avatar, I didn't realize that. Gotcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromium doesn't come bundled with any version of Flash (which I think you know), but instead uses the system version of Flash. This comes in the `flashplugin-installer` package. Technically, this just includes an installer that downloads the actual Flash binary.

You can try removing that package (`sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer`), but that might just remove the installer.