# Adobe Flash Plugin for Chromium

Tags: flash, adobe

I just updated to Ubuntu 16.04 and now my adobe flash plugin for my Chromium browser doesn't work. Any advice? I've tried downloading Pepper Flash, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get latest Flash player on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524279/get-latest-flash-player-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromium Adobe Flash Plugin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/429507/chromium-adobe-flash-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

my guess: copy and see your plugins using chrome://plugins (not sure if it's chromium instead of chrome) if you find two adobe flash plugins disable one of them. If you didn't find any download the package from adobe (.deb for ubuntu) and then install it.

Answer (score 0):

Pepperflash does not work in 32 bit machines anymore since Chrome stopped supporting 32 bit linux.

If you do have a 32 bit Ubuntu installation, then I recommend you download **adobe-flashplugin**.

First remove pepperflash

**sudo apt-get purge --remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree**

**sudo apt-get autoremove**

Install adobe-flashplugin

**sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin**

Once is installed go to [**http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/**](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)

and check that flash 11 is installed.

Comment: Pepper Flash Player still works in Ubuntu 32-bit, and it is in the official repositories for Ubuntu 16.04. Visit the official Ubuntu [Download Page for pepperflashplugin-nonfree_1.8.2ubuntu1_i386.deb on Intel x86 machines](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/download) to download it manually.